# Dictionary-based Auto-suggestions in Android IME

Tags: android

Dictioanry-based suggestions are displayed in a candidate view of IME when we start typing in the textview editor. For example if we type "th" in textview, then words like "this", "that", "the", "there" etc are displayed. I am trying to find out from Android repo source, as how these dictionary-based suggestions are fetched internally. Has anyone tried investigating this ?

Answer (score 1):

I started creating an IME solution for android myself and I am using two things for my auto complete and suggestions. Not sure how this will help you or anyone. But this is what I have done...

I used the user_dict.db as a template database from the /data/data/com.android.providers.userdictionary/databases directory. I searched for the most common english words and imported them into the database. I did a simple database query for words like what the user typed in a new AsyncTask. Also when the user makes a "space" to complete the word, I used Jazzy, which is a spellchecker api for Java, and I took the input from the InputConnection and sent it to Jazzy to check. If the api came up with at least two results I would replace the user word with the first result from Jazzy.

Here is some of the code I used to create the suggestions list.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

.....AsyncTask.......
protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
                list.clear();
            list.add(totalString); // this is the string 
                                   //captured from InputConnection
                Cursor c = db.getNameTitle(totalString); //this is my method in my Database 
//adapter that queries the database and returns a limit of 30 results
                        if(c.moveToFirst()){
                            for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
                                list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter2.KEY_WORD)));
                                if(c.getCount() != i){
                                    c.moveToNext();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        c.close();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         mCandidateView.clear();
         mCandidateView.setCandidatesViewShown(false);
         Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(list.size()));
         if(list.size() > 0 && list.size() < 32){
             mCandidateView.setSuggestions(list, true, true);//CandidateView similar to the SDK's example of SoftKeyboard or LatinIME
         }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone. There may be another way to do this but this words great and it's fast. You may need to figure out the best query that suits your needs.